# cannot find module react-select with material ui example

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am struggling to implement a version of react-select with material ui in my own example. The example given in the documentation is very complicated. https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

When i try to copy the code i get the following errors

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/public/components/select.tsx:13:37
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-select/lib/components/containers'.
```

For the following dependencies.

```
import { ValueContainerProps } from "react-select/lib/components/containers";
import { ControlProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Control";
import { MenuProps, NoticeProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Menu";
import { MultiValueProps } from "react-select/lib/components/MultiValue";
import { OptionProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Option";
import { PlaceholderProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Placeholder";
import { SingleValueProps } from "react-select/lib/components/SingleValue";
import { ValueType } from "react-select/lib/types";
```

I have installed both @types/react-select and react-select.

Answer (score 1):

You can try import like (without the actual path) -

```
import { ValueContainerProps } from "react-select";
```

Also there is no 'lib' folder inside the react-select. Are you sure you are giving the right path?

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided in your post i.e. - https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

This link does not contain any example which imports

```
import { ValueContainerProps } from "react-select/lib/components/containers";
import { ControlProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Control";
import { MenuProps, NoticeProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Menu";
import { MultiValueProps } from "react-select/lib/components/MultiValue";
import { OptionProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Option";
import { PlaceholderProps } from "react-select/lib/components/Placeholder";
import { SingleValueProps } from "react-select/lib/components/SingleValue";
import { ValueType } from "react-select/lib/types";
```

Simple steps to make your [`react-select`](https://react-select.com/home) work,

1. Install `react-select` using,

   `yarn add react-select / npm install react-select --save`
2. Import the default export and render in your component:

   `import Select from 'react-select'`
3. Usage,

   `<Select options={options} />`

You need to pass `options` here, option are nothing but your dropdown options.

```
const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
]
```

Comment: It does check the react-select typescript example.